# This browser or app may not be secure" error has appeared when i am trying to sign-in using selenium webdriver in java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

[image: Error]

I have also turned on the less secure app from the account settings but facing the same problem.

Comment: Are you trying to login to GMail?

Comment: Yes i am trying to automate the gmail login process and want to click on specific email from the unread messages.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you want to login to Gmail. Unfortunately Google forbids using automated scripts for logging into Gmail.

> To help protect your account, Google doesn’t let you sign in from some browsers. Google might stop sign-ins from browsers that:
>
> - Don’t support JavaScript or have JavaScript turned off
> - Have unsecure or unsupported extensions added
> - Are being controlled through software automation rather than a human
> - Are embedded in a different application

See: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7675428?hl=en

You have to use their API if you want to automate Gmail.